# How to install / import a Python package from a specific package?

Tags: python, package

I run a code in Google Colab and get the initial error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/utils_nlp/eval/rouge/rouge_ext.py in <module>()
     23 import collections
     24 
---> 25 from indicnlp.tokenize import sentence_tokenize, indic_tokenize
     26 from ...language_utils.hi.hindi_stemmer import hi_stem
     27 from rouge import Rouge

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'indicnlp.tokenize'
```

How to install (for instance) the `tokenize` package from `indicnlp` ?

I tried

```
!pip install indicnlp.tokenize
```

which apprently doesn't crack it. How to specify from which package to pip install from ?

I also tried

```
!pip install indicnlp
from indicnlp import tokenize
```

which doesn't do it either. I then get the error

```
---> 30 from indicnlp import tokenize
     31 from utils_nlp import eval
     32 from utils_nlp.eval import rouge

ImportError: cannot import name 'tokenize' from 'indicnlp' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/indicnlp/__init__.py)
```

Of course if I just do

```
!pip install tokenize
```

it does't know which tokenize to install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just pip installed the wrong library. On pypi I found another project called [`indic_nlp_library`](https://pypi.org/project/indic-nlp-library/) ([github repo](https://github.com/anoopkunchukuttan/indic_nlp_library)) that seems to have the packages you're looking for. I can get

```
!pip install indic_nlp_library
from indicnlp.tokenize import sentence_tokenize, indic_tokenize
```

to work.

Looks like the `indicnlp` name was taken on pip by another project.